# Golang fmt.Println timer

Tags: go, time, duration

How can I use fmt.Println only every 5 min

```
h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", word)
fmt.Println(h)
```

I need something like this:
**if time := 5 min then fmt.Println(h)**

just to show **(n)** only every 5 min not every line

> **EDIT: Obviously I haven't asked the correct question.**
>
> There is a cycle which generate random digits every second.
>
> ```
> for i := n1; i.Cmp(n2) < 0; i.Add(i, one) {
> ```
>
> What I want is: not to show every generated variable (i) but
>   just one in every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If do something after 5min, simply use `time.AfterFunc`:

```
time.AfterFunc(time.Minute * 5, func() {
    // Do something after 5min
    h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", word)
    fmt.Println(h)
})
```

Else if do something every 5min, use for loop (and go routine if need):

```
for{
    time.Sleep(time.Minute * 5)
    // Do something every 5min
    h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", word)
    fmt.Println(h)
}
```

Other way, use `time.NewTicker` can get a time counter:

```
ticker:=time.NewTicker(time.Minute * 5)
for{
    select{
    case <-ticker.C:
        // Do something every 5min
        h := fmt.Sprintf("%x", word)
        fmt.Println(h)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something only once **after** 5 minutes you can use goroutine and `WaitGroup`:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)

go func() {
   defer wg.Done()
   time.Sleep(...)
   fmt.Println("hello")
}()
wg.Wait()
```

Go playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/UxJ76f44k3x

If you want to do something **every 5 minutes**:

```
func doEvery(d time.Duration, f func(time.Time)) {
    for x := range time.Tick(d) {
        f(x)
    }
}

func helloworld(t time.Time) {
    fmt.Printf("%v: Hello, World!\n", t)
}

func main() {
    doEvery(3*time.Second, helloworld)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0S3MfGlgVRL

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do a task repeatedly. It is up to you which one you choose. Some are listed:

- Simplest way (may be):

  ```
  go func() {
      for {
          fmt.Println("hello")
          time.Sleep(5 * time.Minute)
      }
  }()
  time.Sleep(30 * time.Minute)
  ```
- [func NewTicker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker) returns a new Ticker containing a channel that will send the time with a period specified by the duration argument.

  ```
  ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Minute)
  defer ticker.Stop()
  done := make(chan bool)
  go func() {
      time.Sleep(30 * time.Minute)
      done <- true
  }()
  for {
      select {
      case <-done:
          fmt.Println("Done!")
          return
      case <-ticker.C:
          fmt.Println("hello")
      }
  }
  ```

  https://play.golang.org/p/_Deey4oJDNn
- If you don't like to use the channel, then

  ```
  go func() {
      for range time.Tick(5 * time.Second){
          fmt.Println("hello")
      }
  }()
  time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
  ```

  https://play.golang.org/p/s2efNToSymM
- https://github.com/robfig/cron is also helpful.

  ```
  c := cron.New()
  c.AddFunc("@every 5m", func() { fmt.Println("hello") })
  c.Start()
  select {}
  ```

**UPDATE**

- I have found another link in github: [two ways to call a function every 2 seconds](https://gist.github.com/ryanfitz/4191392)

Comment: I have found another link and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But seems I haven't asked the correct question. Check **EDIT** part and tell me if this is useful :)

Comment: @Mad But you should specify that first.

Comment: yeah sorry for that :(